# How can this equality of sup and maximum be proven?

Tags: real-analysis

Let me first introduce some notation. $\Delta_n$ denotes the probability simplex, i.e. $\Delta_n :=\{(p_0,\dots,p_n):\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} p_i= 1, p_i\ge 0, i=0,\dots,n-1\}$. The confidence region for a Pearson's $\chi^2$ test is defined as 
$$G := \{p\in \Delta_n: \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{(p_i-\hat{p}_i)^2}{2 p_i}\le \frac{1}{2N}\chi^2_{n-1,1-\alpha}\}$$
where $\chi^2_{n-1,1-\alpha}$ is the $1-\alpha$ quantile of a $\chi^2$ distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom. 
For a given vectors $ a_0,\dots,a_{n-1}$ with $a_i\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\epsilon > 0$ we define 
$$H := \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: x = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}q_i a_i,q\in\Delta_n,q\le\frac{1}{\epsilon}p,p\in G\}$$
and one more set is needed. For a fixed $p\in\Delta_n$
$$I(p) := \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: x = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}q_i a_i,q\in\Delta_n,q\le\frac{1}{\epsilon}p\}$$

For my question the probabilistic background doesn't play a role since it's a pure analysis question to establish a certain equality. My notes say based on the definition of the sets $G,I(p)$ and $H$ the following should be true for a $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$

$$\sup_{p\in G}\max_{x\in I(p)} \langle v,x\rangle = \max_{x\in H}\langle v, x\rangle$$
 where $\langle v,x\rangle$ denotes the inner product in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

My attempt so far: The set $H$ uses all $p\in G$ in its definition. Therefore we clearly have for any $p\in G$, $\max_{x\in I(p)} \langle v,x\rangle \ge \max_{x\in H}\langle v, x\rangle$ leading to $\sup_{p\in G}\max_{x\in I(p)} \langle v,x\rangle \ge \max_{x\in H}\langle v, x\rangle$. I'm sturggeling to prove the opposite direction. Any help would be appreciated.

This question arises in the following [paper](http://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjolYSricTTAhVqBsAKHUtsD-EQFggnMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nathankallus.com%2Fpapers%2FDataDrivenRobustOptimization.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEIfGEbTCUhnu9HbIggZ0SxhokZXA) about robust optimization. It's about one step in the proof of theorem 5. The proof can be found in the appendix.

Answer (score 1):

The key observation is that
$$
H=\bigcup_{p\in G}I(p).
$$

**LHS$\ \leq\, $ RHS.**
For all $p\in G$, we have that $I(p)\subseteq H$, and therefore $\max_{x\in I(p)}\langle v,x\rangle\leq \max_{x\in H}\langle v,x\rangle.$ Taking the supremum over $p\in G$ on both sides yields that
$$
\sup_{p\in G}\max_{x\in I(p)}\langle v,x\rangle\leq \max_{x\in H}\langle v,x\rangle.
$$

**LHS$\ \geq\, $ RHS.** Let $x^*\in H$ be a point at which $\langle v,x\rangle$ attains its maximum over $x\in H$. (Such a point exists since $H$ is compact.) Let $p^*\in G$ be a point such that $x^*\in I(p^*)$. Then
$$
\sup_{p\in G}\max_{x\in I(p)}\langle v,x\rangle\geq \max_{x\in I(p^*)}\langle v,x\rangle\geq \langle v,x^*\rangle=\max_{x\in H}\langle v,x\rangle.
$$

---

**Note.** It is easy to see that not only $H$ but also each $I(p)$ is compact, since they are closed subsets of the probability simplex (which is itself compact). The authors are implicitly using this in the notation, by writing $\max\, \langle v,x\rangle$ rather than $\sup\, \langle v,x\rangle$. (Typically one writes $\max$ only when the optimum is attained.)

Comment: Many thanks for the anwser. For me, in the definition of $H$ the $H=\{\dots, p\in G\}$ means that such a $q$ needs to satiafy for all $p\in G$, $q\le\frac{p}{\epsilon}$, i.e. $ H = \cap_p I(p)$. Imho this is the usual definition in such a set description.